# iMovie 11? The Appstore shows 10.0.5

Tags: mac-appstore, imovie

I have iMovie 09. I'm thinking about upgrading, and thought iMovie 11 is the current version. But when I open the Appstore and search for iMovie, I find 10.0.5? What happened to 11?

Answer (score 2):

Product name and actual software version are not always logically linked.

iMovie people are specialist in confusing the customers.

For some reason unknown to man kind they call they 10.0.5 software version the iMovie 11.

I have the latest as of August 2014 and it is actually software version 10.0.5 and nowhere it says 11. (and it is a 2.95 Gig file)

Answer (score 0):

Not true. iMovie 11 is version 9. Latest iMovie is version 10.